# VQMOD plugin for moodle

Tags: php, opencart, moodle

Is there any VQMOD type plugin that is present for Opencart. Any body can give any similar comment. I require this plugin as i want to change the file at run time without changing the core files.

Answer (score 1):

In Moodle there is an option to override the user facing scripts but not libraries or classes etc.

```
// Enabling this will allow custom scripts to replace existing moodle scripts.
// For example: if $CFG->customscripts/course/view.php exists then
// it will be used instead of $CFG->wwwroot/course/view.php
// At present this will only work for files that include config.php and are called
// as part of the url (index.php is implied).
// Some examples are:
//      http://my.moodle.site/course/view.php
//      http://my.moodle.site/index.php
//      http://my.moodle.site/admin            (index.php implied)
// Custom scripts should not include config.php
// Warning: Replacing standard moodle scripts may pose security risks and/or may not
// be compatible with upgrades. Use this option only if you are aware of the risks
// involved.
// Specify the full directory path to the custom scripts
//      $CFG->customscripts = '/home/example/customscripts';
```